# ImageViews in Relativelayout are overlapped.I want to bring the lower imageView on top

Tags: android

i have two imageViews in relativeLayout one top of another.
lets say iv1 is on top of iv2.iv2 can't be seen by the user because it is overlapped by iv1.
Now i want iv2 to be on top of iv1 so that iv1 is completely covered by iv2 and could not be seen.I want to do this by using code.

Example---- You picked a card from the bottom of a deck and placed it on top of the deck.

Sir i have another _imageView2 which is on top of _imageView

```
public void AnimFunction() {

    TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -50, 0, 0);
    animation2.setDuration(100); // duration in ms
    animation2.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    animation2.setFillAfter(false);
    _imageView.startAnimation(animation2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibility to achieve this, something like this ought to work:

```
iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
iv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: But i am using animation with it. iv2 comes from behind iv1 and after coming, it goes back to its place. now it is supposed to be on top of iv1. if i set visibility the effect will be ruined.

Comment: use Animation.Listener to apply the visibility after the animation completes.

Comment: However you right but you didn't understand my problem.Suppose i have two pictures of cards, Card1 and Card2. In the beginning Card1 is on top of Card2, and Card2 is not visible to the user. On an event new card comes out. This is Card2. It animates(comes) from behind of Card1 and it goes back to its orignal position but on top of Card1.Example---- You picked a card from the bottom of a deck and placed it on top of the deck. Please Help! and reply soon....Thank You...

Comment: I didn't understand your question because it is very vague and you've included no source code for me to go off of to figure out what you are trying to do. Also I still think the visibility will work for you somehow, but without seeing any of your code there is really nothing more I can suggest.